# NodeJS: Significance of www

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide

I am new to Node. When I started a new project in C9, I got two automatically generated files: `app.js` and `www` file. I understand what app.js is about, but can't completely figure out what the www is about, what it does.
Could somebody help me understand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `www` is a binary executable that runs your app from the terminal. You should be able to open it as a textfile and check it out.

Comment: In the last tutorial I was following,  I had to execute the app.js... 
Why do I have to execute www now? What's the difference between both of them?

Comment: It's just the difference between running `node app.js` from the terminal or just `.\www` from that directory. `www` may have additional verification checks and stuff in it, though.

Comment: `app.js` no longer runs. I have to run `www` from the terminal....Thant's why I'm confused